# Trouble looping through variables in sas loop

Tags: arrays, sas

Very simple: i'm trying to convert many character variables into numeric. The following code gives the "syntax error, expecting on of the following: a name, -, :, ;" for the drop and rename line.

```
data ex; set ex;
    array numeric{3} var1 var2 var3;
    do i=1 to 8;
        temp = input(strip(numeric(i)),10.);
        drop numeric(i);
        rename temp = numeric(i);
    end;
run;
```

can you not use drop or rename statements in do loops??

Comment: Do any of the character variables contain date representations ? If so, are the representations consistent ?

Comment: None of them are dates. The comment below solved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dataset structure has to be decided when the data step is compiled.  So there is no way you could use an array reference in a rename statement.

If you really have simple numerically suffixed variable names then you could use a simple RENAME statement.

```
rename new1-new3=var1-var3;
```

So your program might be as simple as this:

```
data want;
  set have;
  array ch var1-var3;
  array new new1-new3;
  do index=1 to dim(ch);
    new[index]=input(left(ch[index]),32.);
  end;
  drop index var1-var3;
  rename new1-new3=var1-var3;
run;
```

If the list of names is more complex, like AGE HEIGHT WEIGHT for example, then you will need to use a more complex RENAME statement like:

```
rename new1=AGE new2=HEIGHT new3=WEIGHT ;
```

So use some type of code generation method. Like macro code or using a data step to write lines of code to a file that can be included into the program using `%include` statement.

For example you could make a macro like this:

```
%macro rename(varlist);
%local i;
rename
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&varlist));
   new&i=%scan(&varlist,&i)
%end;
;
%mend ;
```

And use it like this:

```
%let charvars=AGE HEIGHT WEIGHT;

data want;
  set have;
  array ch &charvars;
  array new [%sysfunc(countw(&charvars))];
  do index=1 to dim(ch);
    new[index]=input(left(ch[index]),32.);
  end;
  drop index &charvars;
  %rename(&charvars);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you your solution is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a couple of things incorrectly for SAS.

1. Don't use the same data set name in the DATA/SET statements. It's bad practice and makes it much harder to debug your code.
2. You cannot change the type to the same variable name in the same data step. Often you can rename ahead of time to make this slightly easier.
3. Ideally, especially if the file was read from a text file you fix these issues at the data import stage, not after the fact.

I don't know if the DROP/RENAME statements will take the array variable appropriately, that's something that would need to be tested.

```
data ex1; 
set ex;

*original character variables;
array _chars(3) var1-var3;
*new numeric variables;
array _nums{3} new_var1-new_var3;

do i=1 to 3; *should match size of array;
    _nums(i) = input(strip(_chars(i)), 10.);
end;

drop var1-var3;

*not sure if this will work in the same step;
rename new_var1-new_var3 = var1-var3;

run;
```